# android how to detect if an app is moved to sdcard

Tags: android, app2sd

On rooted phone, how to detect if an application can be moved to sdcard or not?

I know i could check if ApplicationInfo.flags&ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE equals ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or not. But if it is forced to moved to sdcard, is this flag affected?